Multiple switch devices with same gateway IP in one LAN
guys,
I have here a client who use 3 switches in his LAN, but with these switches have the same default IP of 192.168.0.1. My question here is: why the devices(around 30) with manual set IP (from 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.60) can communicate to each other without obvious interruptions?
Also, with the above setup, is there any way to show the network is not stable or cannot work properly?
Thanks in advance,
YH

I suppose your switches are L2, or at least the network is laid out so they don't do any activity besides basic L2. On that level, IP addresses on switches are only used to manage switches themselves; they aren't used during normal switch operation (packet forwarding). OSI level 2 corresponds to Ethernet, which operates with MACs and is indifferent on whatever is above (IP, IPv6, IPX, ATA-over-Ethernet, whatever); it won't be disturbed in any way by duplicate IP addresses.
On the level 3 (IP), however, the devices with conflicting IP addresses will experience problems with communications. But everything else should work nearly normally; there will be hardly any problems with anything that is not trying to communicate with that duplicate IP. On the hosts that do attempt such communication, you may notice flapping entries in the ARP tables (the table that holds IP to MAC correspondences).
That said, as a responsible network administrator you absolutely should fix these IP addressing anomalies to allow for better network control. You don't need to disrupt the current network operation for that; you can assure your customer that you'll be able to change IPs without him noticing (provided that change of management IP address of the switch doesn't impede its L2 operation; I've never seen a switch that has problems with that).
First you need to obtain switch's MAC addresses (most often, printed on the back or on the bottom; you can also display your ARP table, but it will be unpredictable which one you'll see). Then, pick a workstation and set up static ARP entry for one of the switches, in Linux that would be sudo ip neigh add dev eth0 192.168.0.1 lladdr 00:B0:D0:63:C2:26 (or, if there's already an entry for that address, use ip neigh change ...); replace the example MAC with actual switch's. You'll be able to reliably communicate to that switch from that workstation; use that to login and change the IP. Then, repeat this trick for all other switches, until you resolve all the conflicts. At last, remove the static entry with ip neigh del dev eth0 192.168.0.1.

Great! Thanks Nikita, your explaination give me a clear direction to understand the scenairo.  So, under this setup, is there still hardly any problem if this LAN is briging to another LAN with a L3 switch as long as the dupicated IP is not communicated to directly?

L3 switch working in OSI level 3 is a "router in a strict sense", that is, is has and uses the IP routing table, so it considers IP. The communication with misassigned IPs will be impossible. And, you have to do IP setup on these (existing) switches to set up a gateway (or auxiliary route) anyway for such communication, so it would be natural to fix IPs along the way. What you have to understand, it's not the marketing label makes L3 switch L3, it's its configuration. "L3 swich" means it's capable of doing routing, not that it would do it right after you plug it.

Thanks, Nikita. Got the idea. Will see what happens next as the networked workshop being tested.
